# What rails relationship am I looking for here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have multiple models that I want to search such that the results can include results from all of the models.  Let's say I want to do a search for "boots", and I want it to return the boots category as well as retailers who sell boots as well as actual boots.  I have a model for the categories, vendors, as well as the products.

I'd rather not have to create join tables in this case as every object would require a join and this isn't necessary because all objects are to be included in the search.

I'm thinking of using the ransack gem but I don't think this is important to the question because it would be the same regardless of my searching procedure.

Maybe a composed_of relationship makes sense, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Product` `belongs_to` a `Vendor` and `belongs_to` a `Category` here's your query:

```
string_to_search = 'boots'
@products = Product.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{string_to_search}%").includes(:vendor, :category).all
```

It'll fetch all the products with required title's contents along with all their categories and vendors. You can traverse through your resulting data w/o additional queries for fetching category/vendor for a particular product.

If you'll need, say, extract the list of vendors from the `@products` -- just use:

```
@vendors = @products.map &:vendor
```

Comment: That's a slick solution,  my response assumed your search would be on multiple attributes, i.e. in the title,  or a description in the product, or a description attribute in the vendor, etc.  I sort of missed your point about ransack gem,  and I don't know it,  but it sounds like ransack in combination with this answer would be easier than UNIONS warped by ActiveModel.

Comment: This doesn't handle the situation where a category name or vendor property (name, products for sale, etc.) matches the query. I need the results to include vendors, categories, and products because the result set should include matching objects, regardless of type.

Comment: In that case you just need 3 queries: one per model, don't you?

Comment: I'm not sure what I need but my goal is to have a single search box that returns results across multiple models.  I'd like to use a search gem so as not to reinvent many wheels and ransack looks good (the replacement for metasearch).  I'd like to figure out how to have a lazy loading model that, behind the scenes, is just a proxy to the models containing the data.

Comment: As I see this: you run 3 queries to fetch 3 arrays of entities. Then create 3 partials for rendering each type of entities and show them on a result page via `= render @entitiesN` (it's HAML) prepending each section with some headline like `Found among vendors`.

Comment: Your solution would work but it does not take advantage of existing gems and is totally custom. How can I make this work within the confines of RoR models so that I can keep using the awesome gems people are creating for paging and searching?

Comment: Question,  do you want your search interface to be a simple 'one term' search,  or are you going for complex search logic, i.e 'Product contains 'boots' and Vendor contains 'Free Shipping'

Comment: First goal - simple one-term search.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use the UNION operator in a SQL query you craft by hand.   You could create a pseudo Model using ActiveModel, it could act as the aggregator, collecting up the search results from the real models and presenting an ActiveRecord like interface for your queries.

Comment: I am inclined to avoid the SQL manual route as I'll loose lots of RoR goodies. How would I create an aggregation model as you describe?

Comment: My response was ONE solution,  you'd use manual SQL UNIONs,  and wrap it in an ActiveModel to regain the RoR goodies.  Chat me and I can walk you through it

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't see your chat info, how should I connect?

Comment: I've only been invited to chat,  I just set up a Chat room, 'How to Wrap UNION in ActiveModel', see if you can enter that room,  click on chat at the top

Comment: @user1098873,  I think the other answer is still the way to go,  so long as you can tie ALL your models together via associations,  ransack will work for you as a simple way to generate complex search forms with a single 'search_form_for' call.  The only issue is dealing with the results of the search.  You'd just have to do a little work to put the results into a format that makes sense for your app,  but ransack will return enough information that you can figure something out,  joed proposed one solution,  there are probably others.

Comment: @user1098873, Well, not so much that the other answer is the exact way to go,  but a solution is at hand that DOES NOT require UNIONS,  ransack will replace joed's query,  but the point is that you can do it without UNIONs,  the key is that you have associations between the Models,  (I read your post as you not wanting to add associations, what you really said was you don't want Joins).  You don't need joins in your SQL,  you'd just have to simulate the joins after the fact,  they way joed described using map.

Comment: Correction:  You don't need to manually add joins,  I think ransack may add them,  but it's transparent to you.